# make a script that open two terminal and start projects

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I would like to create a script that navigate to 2 project folder, and execute 2 terminal that remain open, so that I don't have to do it everyday.

I tried the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Repository/project1/ && npm run start:debug
cd Repository/project2/local && chmod -x already_made_script.sh
```

but nothing happen. I did :

1. Create file with script
2. chmod u+x myscript.sh
3. tried to call the script or double click on it.

what can I fix.

Sorry.

Comment: Just tried the answer to the linked dupe, still works. Make sure to set your terminal in the head of the script. In case it is not what you are looking for, feel free to mention! (ping me in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

install `konsole` and create 3 scripts:

to run 1 job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1 script
cd Repository/project1/ && npm run start:debug
```

to run 2 job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 2 script
cd Repository/project2/local && chmod -x already_made_script.sh
```

and to run two terminal with 2 jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 3 script
konsole --noclose  -e /bin/bash /path/to/my/script1 &
konsole --noclose  -e /bin/bash /path/to/my/script2
```